# When should embeddings not be used for categorical data? What are their limitations?

Tags: machine-learning, categorical-data, word-embeddings, embeddings

I recently came across the concept of embeddings so the concept is still new to me, but it is my understanding that embeddings convert one-hot encoded input data into a dense vector.

Vectors corresponding to all one-hot encodings are first *embedded* into the dense space randomly. As the embedding gets trained, the vectors *move* in the dense space from their initial random positions to positions that add algebraic meaning to the dense space. The data basically organizes itself.

This process of data arranging itself seems too good to be true.

I am posting this question here because in all the articles I have read about embeddings, they are presented as a *silver bullet*, and I wasn't able to find any texts on the limitations of embeddings.

This would essentially enable all categorical data to be converted into dense, meaningful representations during preprocessing or as part of training of a bigger model).

[This](https://github.com/sachinruk/deepschool.io/blob/master/DL-Keras_Tensorflow/Lesson%2006%20-%20contraception.ipynb) is an example of embeddings being used to convert all categorical features into dense representations:

```
# Input layer for religion
encoder_liv = Sequential()
encoder_liv.add(Embedding(liv_cats,4,input_length=1))
encoder_liv.add(Flatten())

# Input layer for religion
encoder_edu = Sequential()
encoder_edu.add(Embedding(edu_cats,4,input_length=1))
encoder_edu.add(Flatten())

# Input layer for triggers(x_b)
dense_x = Sequential()
dense_x.add(Dense(4, input_dim=x.shape[1]))

model = Sequential()
model.add(Merge([encoder_liv, encoder_edu, dense_x], mode='concat'))
# model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(output_dim=12))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(output_dim=3))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer='adagrad', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

An embedding is used [in this video](https://youtu.be/4VAkrUNLKSo?t=160) to replace the entire encoder network of a convolutional autoencoder generating human faces. [here](https://github.com/HackerPoet/FaceEditor/blob/master/encoder.py) is the accompanying code.

So, what's the catch? Why should I not use always use an embedding for all categorical data? What are the constraints limiting an embedding's use/success?